# Bottle Display Image using File://

Tags: python, bottle

I am trying to display the image on my local machine. I only use the website from my own machine. I am not expecting visit from outside. I found a solution here: [Get Flask to show image not located in the static directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368057/get-flask-to-show-image-not-located-in-the-static-directory), But it doesn't work for me. I have tried:

relative path, abs path. None of them works. Where I did it wrong?

QUESTION:
for test purpose, my file system is like this:

```
C:/jackson/Python34_workspace/Python34_Projects/Learn-Bottle/app05_rend_local_img/
    picuture_gallery/Desert.jpg
    views/index.tpl
    main.py
```

python script is this

```
@bottle.route("/")
def index():
    return bottle.template("index.tpl")

@bottle.post('/result')
def result():
    return bottle.template("index.tpl")
```

And this is my template.

```
<form action="/result" method="POST">

<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<br>
</form>

<div>
    <img src="file:///C:/HSH/Python34_workspace/Python34_Projects/Learn-Bottle/app05_rend_local_img/picture_gallery/Desert.jpg">
</div>
```

--- Some comment ---
I have tried

```
src="file:///picuture_gallery/Desert.jpg"
```

after I clicked submit, it doesn't display. But if I drag it to the browser, it works. How could that be?

Comment: Hi MacSanhe, just place the image in the folder and use relative path instead. It should work

Comment: Could you give me a example? I have tried src="file:///picuture_gallery/Desert.jpg", after I clicked submit, it doesn't display. But if I drag it to the browser, it works. How could that be?

Comment: just `<img src='picture_gallery/Desert.jpg/>` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An URL using the `file` procotol is *never* requested from the server. The client (browser) *always* looks for it on the local system.

So it doesn't matter how you configure your Bottle application, the browser will not ask it for such an URL.

If you want the Botte application to [deliver static files](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#routing-static-files), do something like this:

```
from bottle import static_file
@route('/static/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='/path/to/your/static/files')
```